# ajax success redirect to another page before completing request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have multiple request going from client to server using Ajax. Once all requests are completed , I am sending success message to Ajax success function and then redirecting to different page. but before completing all requests , it get redirected to different page. How to resolve it

Ajax Call

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#btnCreateProg').click(function (e) {
           //alert("hi");
           //debugger;
           //var state = $('#listBoxFormState option:selected').val();
           var states = $.map($('#listBoxFormState option:selected'), function (element) {
               return element.value;
           });
           var checkedboxCount = $("input:checked").length;

           $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (i, ob) {
               //alert($(ob).val());
               var msType = $(ob).val();
               // debugger;
               var NBEffDate = $("#NBEffDate").datepicker().val();
               var RenEffDate = $("#RenEffDate").datepicker().val();
               //debugger;
               jQuery.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "AccelatorUI.aspx/CreateManuscript",
                   data: JSON.stringify({ "manuscriptType": msType, "nbEffDate": NBEffDate.toString(), "renEffDate": RenEffDate.toString(), "states": states, "checkedboxCount": checkedboxCount }),
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (response) {

                       //debugger;
                                                  if (response.d = "success") {
                                                      window.location = "Summary.aspx";
                                                  }
                       //debugger;
                      // window.location = response.d;
                   },

                   error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                       alert('Failed :' + xhr.status + xhr.statusText + xhr.readyState + xhr.responseText + error);
                   }
               });
           });
       });
```

Server Side ( c# code )

```
 [WebMethod]
    public  static string CreateManuscript(string manuscriptType ,string nbEffDate ,string renEffDate ,List<string> states ,string checkedboxCount)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;

        try
        {

            response = "";
            DTO.ManuscriptInfo msInfo = new DTO.ManuscriptInfo();
            DTO.ManuscriptCatlog msCatlog = new DTO.ManuscriptCatlog();

            msInfo.NewBusinessEffDate = nbEffDate;
            msInfo.RenewEffDate = renEffDate;
            msInfo.DCTResponseXML = HttpContext.Current.Session["dctResponseXML"].ToString();
            string catlogFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["catlogPath"];


            msInfo.GenerateManuscriptID(manuscriptType);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["count"] = Int32.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["count"].ToString()) + 1;

            msInfo.GetInheritedManuscriptID();
            msInfo.GetVersionIDforCatlog();

            //foreach ( string state in states )
            //{


             msInfo.CreateManuscript();

             msInfo.SetManuscriptProperties();
             msInfo.CreateFolderStructure();
           // }
            //Response.Redirect("Summary.aspx");



            msCatlog.RandomManuscriptID = msInfo.RandomManuscriptID;
            catlogDataPair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(manuscriptType, msInfo.RandomManuscriptID));
            msCatlog.ManuscriptID = msInfo.ManuscriptID;
            catlogDataPair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(manuscriptType, msInfo.ManuscriptID));

            msCatlog.NewManuscriptPath = msInfo.NewManuscriptPath;
            catlogDataPair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(manuscriptType, msInfo.NewManuscriptPath));
            msCatlog.VersionID = msInfo.VersionID;
            catlogDataPair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(manuscriptType, msInfo.VersionID));

            manuscriptTypeList.Add(manuscriptType);

            List<string> li = new List<string>();

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["count"].ToString() == checkedboxCount)
            {
                foreach (var msItem in manuscriptTypeList)
                {
                    foreach (var item in catlogDataPair)
                    {
                        if (item.Key == msItem)
                        {
                            li.Add(item.Value);
                        }
                    }

                    msCatlog.RandomManuscriptID = li[0];
                    msCatlog.ManuscriptID = li[1];
                    msCatlog.NewManuscriptPath = li[2];
                    msCatlog.VersionID = li[3];
                    msCatlog.CompanyName = msInfo.CompanyName;
                    msCatlog.UpdateManuscriptCatlog();
                    li = new List<string>();
                }

                response = "success";

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(" Exception occurred in static CreateManuscript Method " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }


         return response;
    }
```

Comment: Where are the other requests? I only see one for CreateManuscript?

Comment: For each check box checked , it sends one request. If I have multiple checkboxes checked then it forms multiple requests and send one by one to  CreateManuscript method

Comment: Oh ok. Have you tried counting the number of checkboxes and only redirecting to another page once the last request has been sent?

Comment: Yes . I did. You can see it in my code where I am setting response = "success"; that would come after last request.